# Can anyone help me with this error code in Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm having a go at creating my first data fusion pipeline.
The data is going from Google Cloud Storage csv file to Big Query.

I have created the pipeline and carried out a preview run which was successful but after deployment trying to run resulted in error.

I pretty much accepted all the default settings apart from obviously configuring my source and destination.

Error from Log ...

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 
Forbidden
{
"code" : 403,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "Required 'compute.firewalls.list' permission for 
'projects/xxxxxxxxxxx'",
"reason" : "forbidden"
} ],
"message" : "Required 'compute.firewalls.list' permission for 
'projects/xxxxxxxxxx'"
}
```

After deployment run fails

Answer (score 5):

Do note that as a part of creating an instance, you must set up permissions [0]. The role "Cloud Data Fusion API Service Agent" must be granted to the exact service account, as specified in that document, which has an email address that begins with "cloud-datafusion-management-sa@...".
Doing so should resolve your issue.

[0] : https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-instance#setting_up_permissions

Comment: Thanks for your help. That seemed to work. Well, I've moved on to a different error now :)